# I need help with path times command of asymptote package. How do I find the point of intersection of a line through X=a and a path p?

Tags: asymptote

I do not understand the concept of path times in asymptote package. What does the command
    `times(p,x)`
return? It doesn't seem to return the coordinate of the point of intersection of the path p with the line X=x.

If I want the coordinates of the point of intersection of the path p with the line X=x in the asymptote package how do I get it? According to the asymptote manual it is supposed to return the `path times' of the path, whatever it is. Is it possible to use this find the coordinates of the point?
It will be nice if someone illustrates with a few examples what this path time is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "times" returned by the `times(p,x)` indicate the position along the path relative to the control points of the Bezier curves that make up that path.

You probably want to use the `intersectionpoints(path p, path q)` function instead where `path q` is a vertical line.  `intersectionpoints` returns an array of the intersection coordinates.

The following example code shows how to use both functions.

```
unitsize(1inch);

path p1 = (0,-1){E}..{W}(0,1)--(0.4,1.5);
path p2 = ((0.5,-1)--(0.5,1));

pair[] points = intersectionpoints(p1, p2);
real[] pathtimes = times(p1, 0.5);

draw(p1, red);
draw(p2, blue);
dot(points, 3+black);
dot(p1, 3+green);

label("$y=$"+format("%#0.3f", points[0].y), points[0], SE);
label("$y=$"+format("%#0.3f", points[1].y), points[1], NE);

label("time$=$"+format("%#0.3f", pathtimes[0]), points[0], NE);

dot(Label("time$=0.5$"), point(p1,0.5), E, 3+orange);
dot(Label("time$=1.5$"), point(p1,1.5), E, 3+orange);

draw(subpath(p1, 0.6, 0.8), squarecap+3+green);
dot(point(p1, 0.7), 5+black);
```

**EDIT:** This is in response to your query about the usefulness of the concept of path time.  Many of the path functions take or return path times, so I'm sure there are many uses I haven't thought of.  I've added two more lines to the code above.

1. Using path times and the `subpath` function, it is easy to draw only a portion of a path.  In this case, 20% of the path from 0.6 to 0.8 along the arc length.
2. Using the `point` function, it is easy to mark the position along the arc length.  Suppose that we know that a particle takes one second to move along the arc at constant velocity, the large black dot would then show the position at 0.7 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes things clear. I am just curious.  In which situation would one need path times instead of the exact point of intersection?

Comment: @S.Venkataraman: I added some more content to my answer.

Comment: From the documentation to access points at a given percentage `relpoint(path p, real l)` returns the point on path p at the relative fraction l of its arclength. See also `reltime(path p, real l)`.