# How to get points on a 3D curve (to make 3D animation) in Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote, animations

I want to make 3D animation in Asymptote: the blue small sphere moving along the 3D cyclic curve (that I named "orbit8"). I have heard that curves in Asymptote are parameterized. However, I don't know how to get positions of points along the orbit.

Could you please help me!

My MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import three;
currentprojection=obliqueX;
unitsize(1cm);
draw(O--4 * X,Arrow3); 
draw(O--4 * Y,Arrow3); 
draw(-1*Z--4 * Z,Arrow3); 
label("$x$", 4 * X, NW);
label("$y$", 4 * Y, SE);
label("$z$", 4 * Z, E);
real a=.4;
triple U=(-a,-a,1),L=(a,a,1);
path3 orbit8=
(0,1,2)..(0,2,1)..(0,1,0)..U..(1,0,2)..(2,0,1)..(1,0,0)..L..cycle;
draw(orbit8,1bp+black);
dot(L,8bp+.8blue);
dot(U,5bp+.8red);
draw((0,0,2)--(0,0,4),6bp+green,Arrow3()); 
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please use a MWE that contains the ``\documentclass``, all the ``\usepackage``s (and libraries if you use ``tikz`` or something like that), as well as the ``\begin{document}`` and ``\end{document}``

Comment: @Vinccool96 oh, it's usual in writing Asymptote code: just save with xxx.asy in Texmaker, then press F1 to typeset. Is that okay?

Comment: Something [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478427/asymptote-package-generating-unwanted-margins) would be preferable

Comment: I have just improved my MWE as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `point(orbit8,t)` where `t` is a time. I recommend [this great tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) as well as the `asypictureB` package by the author of the tutorial. That way you create the output with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>`, where `file` could contain

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=asyani}
import three;
currentprojection=obliqueX;
unitsize(1cm);
draw(O--4 * X,Arrow3); 
draw(O--4 * Y,Arrow3); 
draw(-1*Z--4 * Z,Arrow3); 
label("$x$", 4 * X, NW);
label("$y$", 4 * Y, SE);
label("$z$", 4 * Z, E);
real a=.4;
triple U=(-a,-a,1),L=(a,a,1);
path3 orbit8=
(0,1,2)..(0,2,1)..(0,1,0)..U..(1,0,2)..(2,0,1)..(1,0,0)..L..cycle;
draw(orbit8,1bp+black);
dot(L,8bp+.8blue);
draw((0,0,2)--(0,0,4),6bp+green,Arrow3()); 
dot(point(orbit8,0.5),5bp+.8red);
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is just for fun: creating an actual animation. This snippet creates a series of pdf files that can be converted to an animated gif as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799). [Asymtote has its own facilities to produce animations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421916/121799), but I personally often use [these methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/421887/121799) (but this may just be me). The most important ingredient here is [relpoint, which O.G. pointed out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479338/how-to-get-points-on-a-3d-curve-to-make-3d-animation-in-asymptote/479358?noredirect=1#comment1211680_479358), so full credit goes to them.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{orbiter.asf}
\begin{asypicture}{name=asyani}
import three;
currentprojection=obliqueX;
unitsize(1cm);
real mytime = @mytime;
draw(O--4 * X,Arrow3); 
draw(O--4 * Y,Arrow3); 
draw(-1*Z--4 * Z,Arrow3); 
label("$x$", 4 * X, NW);
label("$y$", 4 * Y, SE);
label("$z$", 4 * Z, E);
real a=.4;
triple U=(-a,-a,1),L=(a,a,1);
path3 orbit8=
(0,1,2)..(0,2,1)..(0,1,0)..U..(1,0,2)..(2,0,1)..(1,0,0)..L..cycle;
draw(orbit8,1bp+black);
dot(L,8bp+.8blue);
draw((0,0,2)--(0,0,4),6bp+green,Arrow3()); 
dot(relpoint(orbit8,mytime),5bp+.8red);
\end{asypicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\standaloneenv{asypicture}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\myangle{45}
\foreach \mytime in {0,0.025,...,0.975}
{
\RequireAsyRecompile
\input{orbiter.asf}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, marmot! i did not read the tutorial carefully.

Comment: From the documentation to access points at a given percentage `relpoint(path p, real l)` returns the point on path p at the relative fraction l of its arclength.

Comment: @O.G. Thanks! Could you perhaps also add this information to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392518/121799 ?